# When you buy an uncooked frozen pizza, if it is soft does that mean it hasn’t been frozen?

Tags: pizza

I just wanted to know... Is it safe to eat if the pizza was soft after being bought frozen from the store... it wasn’t mushy or anything, but it was a little soft. I’ve never had a frozen pizza before but I do know that frozen food is kinda supposed to be harder. Someone please answer this question.

Comment: Did you just pull it out of your freezer or did you just get it home from the store? Has it been out of the freezer for a bit - if so, how long?

Answer (score 3):

If the pizza wasn't exposed to anything or just left sitting out for hours on end, it should be fine. Thawing and refreezing over short periods of time won't do much, but they may effect the taste/quality of the food.

You should be fine!